# Are the gravitational redshift and blueshift factors inverses of each other?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics

at a point in gravitational field assuming swcharzschild metric and the exact analysis. The other point in context is infinity. It would be helpful if you can provide citation/source of the answer/equations.

Comment: what was the question?

Comment: Come on chaps, it seems clear to me what the OP is asking. If you shine a light in then back is the product of the inbound and outbound frequency shift unity?

Comment: @JohnRennie You should edit the question to make that more apparent. One more step towards the refiner badge for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are.

If you have an observer $1$ at infinity and an observer $2$ in the gravity well then the frequency shift is just a function of the [time dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Outside_a_non-rotating_sphere):

$$ \frac{dt_2}{dt_1} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r_2}} $$

That is, observer $2$'s clock runs slower than observer $1$'s clock by a factor of $\sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r_2}}$. The corollary is that observer $1$'s clock runs faster than observer $2$'s clock by the reciprocal of this factor.

So if observer $1$ sends a light ray to observer $2$, and $2$ just reflects it back with a mirror, then the light $1$ gets back is the same frequency as the light they originally transmitted.

Actually I suppose this is obvious because if it wasn't true energy wouldn't be conserved.

Comment: I was expecting this. Great many thanks John, you could get what I asked for even if i wasn't clear.